# Allow ENTER for next line in Multiple line EDIT BOX

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, multiline, editcontrol

I have multiline Edit Box (MFC). If user press Enter, the default push button have pushed and dialog ends (obviously).
How to allow user to use <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key for the next line in edit box?
I read, that I should to use `ES_WANTRETURN` style for this EDIT_CONTROL, but how to do it? If I have not create procedure? I have modal dialog generated from *.rc file.
Thanks for helping. I need some easy way :-)

Comment: If you have used a dialog resource, change it there. Otherwise you can use the `SetWindowLong()` function (after the control is created, but before it is displayed).

Answer (score 3):

### Resource Editor

I set a few properties in the resource editor for the `CEdit` control:

[image]

- **Horizontal Scroll** - I set it to false otherwise the text will not word wrap.
- **Vertical Scroll** - I set it to true so that you can still view all text when it becomes too much for the control to display.
- **Multiline** - Set it to true because we want multiline.
- **Want Return** - Set this to true if you want the user to insert a new line when they press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (when the control has focus).

---

### Resource File

In my RC file such a control is defined like this:

```
EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT_NOTES_OPENING,15,27,200,32,ES_MULTILINE | ES_WANTRETURN | WS_VSCROLL
```